# how android layout inflate mechanism working in fragment?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am a beginner about android. For the past 6 months, I have been using the following code to display the layout in `listview`, fragment and add custom header.

```
(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(layout,view, false);

LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(layout, null);
```

But i do not understand the functionality, and what it describes, and how it is working. Please kindly explain those if you know. Sorry for my bad English.