# What is the different between the various form of inflate() method

Tags: android

May be the Question sounds silly. what is the difference between these calling of `inflate()` method.

```
LayoutInflater lif = getLayoutInflater();

View v = lif.inflate(Resource, null);
//VS
View v = lif.inflate(Resource, parent);
//Vs
View v = lif.inflate(Resource, parent, boolean);
```

What `v` reference to in different way of calling this method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you need to understand his all parameter see my answer! :)

Comment: As all of the answers seem to be copy-pastes of the docs, I'll just link them here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html
Learning to read the docs is crucial to broaden your mind on programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View Groups are always used to add a child view or inflate your custom view in your application

In the given method prototypes the first parameter points to the layout resource you want to inflate. The second parameter is the root view of the hierarchy you are inflating the resource to attach to. If there is the presence of any third parameter is present, it governs whether or not the inflated view is attached to the supplied root after the inflation.

```
 1. View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)
    Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.

 2. View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)
    Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml node.

 3. View inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
    Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified XML node.

 4. View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)
    Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.
```

for more please visit

- [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)
- [How android layout inflate mechanism working in fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18843191/how-android-layout-inflate-mechanism-working-in-fragment)

Comment: @Kedarnath many thanks for kedarnath ji for editing, i will make sure for these perfect editing in future:)